# Url Rewriting regex

Tags: php, regex, mod-rewrite

I have this rule in my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ ?page=user&id=$1 [L]
```

It rewrite a url like

```
http://sitename.ext/nickname
```

to

```
http://sitename.ext/?page=user&nickname
```

The problem is that with a url with dots like `http://sitename.ext/nick.name.test` i get a 404 error..

I'm not good with regex..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because it's not being rewritten. You specificaly told it to exclude `.`, and that's what it's doing.

Personally, I would favour something like this:

```
RewriteRule user/(.+) ?page=user&id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Don't forget to exclude any trailing slash, if present.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match any character except a slash, the regex is `[^/]`, since the `\.` will cause it also to not match dots.

Your rule should be

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?page=user&id=$1 [L]
```

You might find [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) site helpful.

Comment: mmh.. The regex i want to make is that must match a-z, A-Z, 0-9, underscores and dots.. and also if is present or not a final shash.. `RewriteRule ^([\w\.]+)/?$ ?page=user&id=$1 [L]` this may do the job? Thank you..